# Handle Filter and OpenArgs

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Continuation of some possibilities for my existing project.

I am looking into handling the probability that someone, after me, would pass OpenArgs or Where values, via OpenForm, and I was wondering if there was a way to "catch and release" the values as invalid.

I figured in OpenArgs i would handle it through `Open`, unless i misread the information on MSDN (which is possible considering the abstract obfuscation of the information).

1. My question is more of how do I catch someone passing the Where value to a form?
2. Is there a One-Stop Shop where i can catch both of them or will i have to handle two Events?

Looking to try and kill both "birds" with one "stone", if possible.  I plan on abstracting both events to a standard method located in a Module, but need to start somewhere first.

Comment: You want the form to reject `OpenArgs` and filter `WhereCondition` values passed from an `OpenForm` call? Naturally a form will ignore `OpenArgs` unless you specifically use it somewhere in your form code.

Comment: Its more about Alerting the enduser to inform IT that a Form that should not have been passed a Filter or OpenArg was.  Kind of an alert system.

Comment: As an optional way of implementation, i posted the code-snippets that i used here at [Microsoft Wikia](http://microsoft.wikia.com/wiki/Microsoft_Access/Snippets/Forms#Filter.2FOpenArgs_Validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where will limit the recordset by a filter. You can check the filter property for the form. Openargs is separate.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Debug.Print "Open filter " & Me.Filter & " is on " & Me.FilterOn
End Sub
```

Comment: So i can do Filter & OpenArgs all in the the `OnOpen` event?